# Factory with raw pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm designing a Factory in C++ with raw pointers, but I'd like to use smart pointers when possible as is recommended with the Factory pattern in newer C++. Unfortunately my compiler is a *bit* old (gcc 4.4.6) and not all of the features of C++11 (let alone C++0x) are available to me.

I cannot use `nullptr`, which is the most troubling aspect to me. I'd love a standard review and any tips for adding smart pointers to my code.

```
#ifndef SERVICE_FACTORY_H_
#define SERVICE_FACTORY_H_

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Service {
  public:  
    virtual void free() = 0;
};

typedef Service* (*CreationFunction)(void);

class Counter : public Service {
  public:
    static Service* create() { return new Counter(); }
    void free() { delete this; }
};

class ServiceFactory {
  public:
    ~ServiceFactory() {
      _registeredServices.clear();
    }

    static ServiceFactory* getInstance() {
      static ServiceFactory instance;
      return &instance;
    }

    void registerService(const std::string &serviceName, CreationFunction fn) {
      _registeredServices[serviceName] = fn;
    }

    Service* createService(const std::string &serviceName) {
      auto it = _registeredServices.find(serviceName);
      if(it != _registeredServices.end())
        return it->second();
      return NULL;
    }
  private:
    ServiceFactory() {
      registerService("COUNTER", &Counter::create);
    }

    ServiceFactory(const ServiceFactory&) { /* Nothing implemented yet */ }

    ServiceFactory& operator=(const ServiceFactory&) { return *this; }

    std::map<std::string, CreationFunction> _registeredServices;
};

#endif // SERVICE_FACTORY_H_
```

**EDIT**

Here's a driver:

```
#include "ServiceFactory.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Service* counter = ServiceFactory::getInstance()->createService("COUNTER");
  if(counter) {
    std::cout << "Counter was made." << std::endl;
    counter->free();
  } else {
    std::cout << "Counter was not made." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the compilation process succeeding on [ideone](https://ideone.com/edt0OD) (with C++14).

Comment: Next time, please wait for the question to be reopened instead of posting it again.  The previous one had already received reopen votes.

Comment: You can always use `boost` it has all the smart pointers that are in the standard (its where they came from after all).

Comment: Also you don't need to return smart pointers. You could return references. Let the factory retain ownership of the objects (but that depends a bit on the usage model).

Comment: @LokiAstari I want to create an arbitrary number of services, so I don't want to user to be responsible for deleting them all.

Comment: @erip: Yep. I would not want the user responsible for deleting any of them. But that does not necessarily means shared pointers. If resources can be shared then reference may be an alternative. But it really depends on the usage pattern.

Comment: Voting to close as the code generates 12 errors when you try and compile it. Obviously untested and sample code.

Comment: Check here on how to write a singelton: [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065)

Comment: Check here on the classic factory pattern [How to implement the factory method pattern in C++ correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121930/14065)

Comment: If you don't have a modern version of C++ you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/) to get all the modern C++ facilities. This is the proving ground that libraries go through before they are added to the standard. So it has shared pointers and can be used with C++03

Comment: Also note that g++ 4.6 supports some C++11 features with `-std=c++0x` flag

Comment: 1. This is not a singleton, it's a global static object.
2. Note that I have `gcc 4.4.6` available to me, not `4.6`.
3. It generates no errors on my compiler. It is tested on `gcc 4.4.6` (as mentioned).

Comment: Further, you can't compile a header file.